# FPDF Error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file. Tried everything but nothing helped

Tags: php, html, ms-access, pdf, fpdf

I know there are many and many others questions like this.
But please, I tried everything but nothing worked.

I tried deleting every other strings before and after FPDF or the PHP tags.
Please help me

```
<?php    
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
require ('../../php/extras/fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf -> AddPage();
$pdf -> SetFont('Arial','', 14);

$percorso = realpath("./db/comuni.mdb");
$sc="DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=".$percorso.";";
$cn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Non va ADO");
$rs = new COM("ADODB.Recordset");
$id = $_GET['idcomune'];
  for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($id) ; $i++, next($id)){
    $cn->Open($sc);
    echo $id[$i];
    $rs->Open("SELECT * FROM comuni  WHERE idcomune = $id[$i]", $cn);
    echo "<P>";

    echo'<H2>'.$rs->fields['idcomune']->value.'</H2>';
    echo'<H3>'.$rs->fields['CAP']->value."</H3>";
    echo'<H1>'.$rs->fields['comune']->value."</H1>";
    echo'<H4>'.$rs->fields['idprov']->value."</H4>";

    echo'</P>';

    $pdf -> Cell(60, 10, $rs->fields['comune']->value , 0, 1, 'C');

    $rs->movenext();

    $cn->close();
  }

  $pdf->Ln();
  $pdf->Output();
  ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I want a PDF file that shows the the result of the query

Answer (score 0):

You have `echo`s in your code ; it looks like you are trying to mix HTML output and pdf output at the same time.

If you want to serve both HTML and pdf, you have to do do with two separate routes.

Comment: How can I pass query results to another routes?

Comment: Write a function, which returns the query's result, and use this function in both routes